# how to run a php code on clicking a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

I am working on a module, "who viewed your profile" in a social networking site project. When a logged in user clicks on hyperlink of a user, he must be directed to a dummy page called view.Information of user who has clicked link of other user and username of user whose link has been clicked is stored in a database table, views. I tried doing this by calling a function updatetable on click of the hyperlink and using this function, I want to send variables viewername and viewedname to view.php, which inserts a record into views table.

```html
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
     <a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php" onclick="updatetable('<?php echo  $row['username']; ?>','<?php echo  $username; ?>')"><?php echo  $row['username']; ?></a>
<?php
 }
```

The above code displays links of all users and if a link is clicked, view.php page is opened where some php code has to be run.
My updatetable function is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewedname,viewername;
function updatetable(viewedname,viewername)
{
$.post('view.php' { viewer_name:viewername, viewed_name:viewedname } );
alert(viewedname);
}
</script>
```

view.php code:

```html
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['viewer_name']) && isset($_POST['viewed_name'])) {
 $viewer_name = ($_POST['viewer_name']);
    $viewed_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['viewed_name']);
 $con=new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
if($con->connect_error) echo $con->connect_error;
$r=mysqli_query($con,"insert into views(viewer,viewed) values('$viewer_name','$viewed_name')");
}
```

Problems that I am facing:
alert is not being shown and insertion is not happening after view.php code.
Is there a mistake in the way I'm sending the viewer_name and viewed_name variables?
I am new to php. Please help me out! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Missing a (`,`) in your javascript post:

**Replace with:**

```
$.post('view.php', { viewer_name:viewername, viewed_name:viewedname });
```

**PHP:**

Its better doing it this way:

```
if ($_POST){
  if(isset($_POST['viewer_name']) && isset($_POST['viewed_name'])) {
   //Do your stuff
  }
}
```